# How could I use the if function to verify if index count is true or false?

Tags: string, if-statement, indexing, printing

I have literally just begun self teaching some programming and decided to start with Python.
As I've been going through the very first few exercises, I thought to myself how can I write something that tells me whether the index count of the string is what I think it is? Something along the lines of

```
astring = "Hello world!"
if (astring.index ("H") = 0) = True
print true
```

I know it's mega noob stuff but I was curious cos I couldn't do it myself and couldn't find similar questions or probably really understand those that were. Cheers all

EDIT:thank you all for the helpful answers! interesting to see there are multiple paths to the same solution. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_string = "Hello world"
if (my_string[0] == "H"):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

`my_string[0]` accesses the 0th element (character) in the word, and the `==` is the comparator

Answer (score 0):

You can look for [string index()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_index.asp). It returns the index of a character in the string.

```
if (astring.index("H")) == 0:
   print("True")
```

Answer (score 0):

WelCome to the wonderfull world of PowerShell.

The PowerShell way could be like this:

```
$string = "Hello World"
If ($string.indexof("H") -eq 0) {"Do Something"}
```

indexOf("H") returns the index position of H in this case 0. Compare that with the -eq parameter and you're done.

Comment: I can't seem to get this method to work , it gives me a syntax error at 0

Comment: got it to work this way
if (astring.index("H") == 0): print ("Do Something")

using indexof gives the error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
    if (astring.indexof("H") == 0): print ("Do Something")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'indexof'